# How can I generate different DOM elements based on JSON properties in Angular?

Tags: json, angular

As part of my application one of the features involves displaying release notes to the user when a new version of the app has been deployed. These release notes are stored in the backend in JSON format, with the structure as below.

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "workItems": [
        {
            "id": 18391,
            "title": "Release Note Item Title",
            "elements": [
                {
                    "elementType": 1,
                    "elementData": [
                        "Release note item paragraph"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "elementType": 2,
                    "elementData": [
                        "Release note list item 1",
                        "Release note list item 2",
                        "Release note list item 3"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Within the JSON file there is the `version` number, as well as an array of `workItem` object, each object contains an Id, Title, and then an inner array `elements` which stores the textual elements that need to be displayed to the user. Each element in the `elements` array is a separate structure, with `elementType` representing exactly what type of HTML element needs to be displayed.

```
1 = Paragraph
2 = Unordered list
```

So `elements[0]` represents `<p>Release note item paragraph</p>`

While `elements[1]` represents

```
<ul> 
    <li>Release note list item 1</li>
    <li>Release note list item 2</li>
    <li>Release note list item 2</li>
</ul>
```

What I need to do is figure out a way that I can render the appropriate HTML tags according to the value of `elementType` for each object. Since Angular 
dis-encourages the manual manipulation of the DOM I'm not sure how to proceed.

I have considered printing all of the elements and then using *ngIf to somehow determine which HTML elements are displayed to the user, but as far as I am aware *ngIf is solely for determining whether or not the element is displayed i.e. manipulating the CSS of already existing HTML elements, and can't be used to conditionally render certain HTML ahead of time.

```
<div *ngFor="let element of data.elements">
    <p *ngIf="element.elementType === '1'">{{element.elementData}}</p>
</div>
```

I've tried the above, but this obviously doesn't work.

I feel like this isn't something that can be achieved in the template and instead will be need to done in the component first and then pushed to the template. Would it work if I instead built the HTML strings within the component using the JSON data ahead of time and then had the template display them incrementally?

Comment: have you tried without quotes around the number in your template ?
`*ngIf="element.elementType === 1"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let data of dataSet.workItems">
    <div *ngFor="let element of data.elements">
        <p *ngIf="element.elementType == 1">{{element.elementData[0]}}</p>
        <ul *ngIf="element.elementType == 2">
            <li *ngFor="let list of element.elementData">
                {{list}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2qjegm?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. Not sure how I didn't work this out, it's quite simple really. Does this also render DOM elements that are not being used? For example if a <p> has an elementType of 2, is the <p> still rendered and then hidden? Or is it never rendered in the first place?

Comment: Using `ngIf`, it isn't rendered in DOM, to hide, you can use `[hidden]`

Comment: Please try to avoid using double equality (==) in your checks to avoid potential logic errors and for performance. Prefer strict equality (===).

Answer (score 0):

'elementType' in your JSON data is a number but you compare it to a string in the template (using quotes around the number).
Try this instead:

```
<div *ngFor="let element of data.elements">
    <p *ngIf="element.elementType === 1">{{element.elementData[0]}}</p>
</div>
```